# Round to nearest multiple of 60 in a column

Tags: awk, rounding

I have a rather large textfile with 2 columns (ID, time shift in minutes) and I would like to round up the second column of this file to the nearest multiple of +/- 60 (i.e., hours).

Some sample output of the file:

```
 la-1039 -11
 po-3712 270
 aa-1001 -60
 zu-1999 -111
 oi-9462 361
```

I would like the output to be:

```
 la-1039 0
 po-3712 4
 aa-1001 -1
 zu-1999 -2
 oi-9462 6
```

I know awk can do math, but am having difficulty with the rounding aspect. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `x + 59 / 60`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `printf` rounding, with `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s %.0f\n", $1, $2/60}' file

la-1039 -0
po-3712 4
aa-1001 -1
zu-1999 -2
oi-9462 6
```

Comment: are you sure that would round 0.5 up rather than down or to the nearest even number or something else?

Comment: Not sure, if I remember correctly it should be the nearest integer, for 0.5 it's nearest even as convention, otherwise there would be a bias.

Comment: yeah, nearest even sounds right to me for 0.5 but i'd have to look it up (which I'm not going to do). I think the OP wants to round up though.

Comment: title says nearest, description says round up.  *The formulation of a problem is often more essential than its solution...*

Comment: The implementation you give using `printf` is _"round to nearest and ties to even"_